# When $0<a<b$ and $x+y=n$, prove $a^{n}<a^{x}b^{y}<b^{n}$ for all positive integers $n$. Can this be proved by induction?

Tags: inequality

I am stuck after the following step.

$a^{n+1}<a^{x+1}b^{y}$ and $a^{x}b^{y+1}<b^{n+1}$.

Here $x+y+1=n+1$ but is it enough to prove the result by induction?

Just realised the statement could be rewritten as $a^{n}<a^{x}b^{n-x}<b^{n}$.

Couldn't prove it by induction but got an idea for an alternate proof from the comment of @kingW3 and the answer of @Arnaldo Nascimento.

Proof:

For $0<x$, $0<y$, and $0<n$.

$a^{y}<b^{y}\Rightarrow a^{y}a^{x}<b^{y}a^{x}\Rightarrow a^{n}=a^{x+y}<b^{y}a^{x}$ and $a^{x}<b^{x}\Rightarrow a^{x}b^{y}<b^{x}b^{y}\Rightarrow a^{x}b^{y}<b^{x+y}=b^{n}$. Therefore, $a^{n}<a^{x}b^{y}<b^{n}$.

Comment: $b^xb^y>a^xb^y>a^xa^y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $c=b/a>1$. Then $b=ac$, so $a^xb^y=a^xa^yc^y=a^nc^y$ and the inequality to be proved is
$$
a^n<a^nc^y<a^nc^n
$$
that is,
$$
1<c^y<c^n
$$
which holds if and only if $0<y<n$.

Comment: The fact that $n$ must be positive ended up being really important in a proof I just did.

Comment: @shredalert Also $x$ and $y$ must be positive.

Comment: Yes, that was important too.

Answer (score 1):

$a^x=a^{n-y}=a^n.a^{-y}$ and $b^y=b^nb^{-x}$ so

$$a^xb^y=\frac{a^nb^n}{a^yb^x}<\frac{a^nb^n}{a^ya^x}=\frac{a^nb^n}{a^{x+y}}=b^n$$

$$a^xb^y=\frac{a^nb^n}{a^yb^x}>\frac{a^nb^n}{b^yb^x}=\frac{a^nb^n}{b^{x+y}}=a^n$$

and then

$$a^n<a^xb^y<b^n$$

Comment: There are some implicit assumptions in this argument.